# Unable to insert UUID as integer in primary key column of a table created in spanner database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-spanner

I have model written in declarative base of SQL Alchemy.

```
Class Roles(Base):
    __tablename__ = "roles"
    __table_args__ = (
        Index("roles_name", "name", unique=True),
    )

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, default=get_uuid())
    name = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
```

As you may have noticed I have set the default value of primary key column `id` to `get_uuid()`.

```
def get_uuid():
    pk = uuid.uuid4().int >> 64
    return pk
```

The above method return UUID as integer of bit size 64 or less. This is because the column `id` of this table is set to int and spanner can hold up to 64 bit.

So now to insert a row in this table -

```
>>> role = Roles()
>>> role.name = "Admin"
>>> session.add(role)
>>> session.commit()
```

This resulted in following exception -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 72, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION
        details = "Could not parse 18011687921562567628 as an integer"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:172.19.0.3:9010 {grpc_message:"Could not parse 18011687921562567628 as an integer", grpc_status:9, created_time:"2022-11-12T06:48:36.468914625+00:00"}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_dbapi/cursor.py", line 269, in execute
    ) = self.connection.run_statement(statement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_dbapi/connection.py", line 454, in run_statement
    _execute_insert_heterogenous(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_dbapi/_helpers.py", line 57, in _execute_insert_heterogenous
    transaction.execute_update(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_v1/transaction.py", line 302, in execute_update
    response = api.execute_sql(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_v1/services/spanner/client.py", line 1096, in execute_sql
    response = rpc(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 154, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 283, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 190, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 99, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 74, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 Could not parse 18011687921562567628 as an integer

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sqlalchemy_spanner/sqlalchemy_spanner.py", line 1013, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_dbapi/cursor.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return function(cursor, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_dbapi/cursor.py", line 289, in execute
    raise IntegrityError(getattr(e, "details", e)) from e
google.cloud.spanner_dbapi.exceptions.IntegrityError: []

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1451, in commit
    self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 829, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3386, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3525, in _flush
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3486, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 456, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 630, in execute
    util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    _emit_insert_statements(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1238, in _emit_insert_statements
    result = connection._execute_20(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1705, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 333, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1572, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1943, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2124, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sqlalchemy_spanner/sqlalchemy_spanner.py", line 1013, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_dbapi/cursor.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return function(cursor, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/spanner_dbapi/cursor.py", line 289, in execute
    raise IntegrityError(getattr(e, "details", e)) from e
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (google.cloud.spanner_dbapi.exceptions.IntegrityError) []
[SQL: INSERT INTO roles (id, name) VALUES (%s, %s)]
[parameters: [18011687921562567628, 'Admin']]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

What I understood for this is that the spanner is not willing to accept the generated UUID.

```
status = StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION
details = "Could not parse 18011687921562567628 as an integer"
```

I have checked the method `get_uuid()`. It does return int value of but size 64 or less.

The README of this [repo](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy/) suggests [creating a table's primary key as Integer](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy#create-a-table) and [while in inserting a row in the database generate value of primary key in hex](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy#insert-a-row). I did exactly the same but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The generated int value is larger than the maximum `INT64` value that is allowed in Cloud Spanner:

- Max allowed: `9223372036854775807`
- Your value : `18011687921562567628`

See https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#integer_types for more information on the `INT64` type.

I'm no Python expert, but my guess is that the int value that you are generating is interpreted as an unsigned int, while the `INT64` data type in Cloud Spanner is signed.

EDIT: Add example to get signed value.

My understanding is that you can do the following to get a signed 64-bit integer value from a UUID in Python:

```py
import ctypes
import uuid

ctypes.c_long(uuid.uuid4().int >> 64).value
```